# Swift: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on accessing JSON URL

Tags: json, swift3

I'm currently learning about JSON and View Controllers, 
and I'm getting this error while clicking on Tab Bar

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

The error appears in this line (please see the picture below), on accessing URL

I uploaded the project [here](https://github.com/lindafitriani/NxRadioJSON) to make it easy to analyze the error

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `guard` statement is useless because you're forced unwrapping the value in the parentheses.

To make the `guard` statement fully functional you need a second optional binding:

```
guard let stationURL = nxCurrentStation?.stationStreamURL, 
      let streamURL = URL(string: stationURL) else { ...
```

Comment: perfect, Thanks a lot